# What use is Cutting Fluid?

Tags: fallout-4

I've noticed in the Chemistry Workshop I have the ability to craft *Cutting Fluid*:

[image: Cutting Fluid in the crafting menu]

The [wiki entry](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cutting_fluid) is currently a little vague on details, only explaining that it can be broken down into some base parts again. So what is the use of Cutting Fluid?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only use of Cutting Fluid I've been able to observe so far, is that it can be scrapped for Oil, which is one of the most used components you'll ever find in the wastelands, along with adhesive.

For adhesive, you have Vegetable Starch, which can be cooked in any Cooking Station.

Comment: Fair enough. I just figured it must've been used in a recipe or something. Seems a little backward that it's only use it to craft it then de-craft it back into oil haha. Oh well.

Comment: @Robotnik: Could also be it will be used more in new DLC.

Comment: @Robotnik Oil is not an ingredient in making it. Steel and purified water are extremely common (assuming you have purifiers making water), and bone and acid are not too hard to find. It's not quite as convenient as Vegetable Starch, but it's a good way to get extra oil.

Comment: @DCShannon - I realise that, my point was if it's only use is to be made into oil, why not just make the recipe output 'oil'? Why 'Cutting Fluid' specifically?

Comment: @Robotnik Ah, okay, I see what you're saying. I'd imagine just for flavor, although if the weight or value of the cutting fluid is significantly different than the oil you can get from it, that might be a factor as well.